# To sum all corresponding fields of 2nd column for each occurrence of fields in the first column

Tags: awk

```
$ bpimagelist -l -d 11/01/2013 03:27:13 -e 11/01/2013 03:30:00 | awk '/^IMAGE/ {print $2, $19}'

XXclcnpde148-bak.XX 11808

XXclnXXcXXcde010-bak.XX 26400

XXcwcnpde148-bak.XX 1623072

XXcwcnpde207-bak.XX 672

XXcwcnpde207-bak.XX 672

XXcwcnpde209-bak.XX 672

XXcwcnpde209-bak.XX 672

XXcwcnpde209-bak.XX 672

-
-
-
- and continues
```

My output has 2 columns, i need an awk linux command to sum all corresponding fields of 2nd column for each occurrence of fields in the first column. Then  print unique values of column 1 and its corresponding sum in column to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sum of columns 2 with columns 1 as id :

```
awk '{sum2[$1] += $2}; END{ for (id in sum2) { print id, sum2[id] } }' < input
```

Here $1 is the id field, $2 is the column 2. We build 1 arrays for summing columns 2. Once we've processed all the lines/records, we iterate through the array keys (id strings), and print the value at that array index.

Comment: thanks, below command worked well awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (x in a) print x, a[x]}' file Please let me know how to get the sorted output. sort columnn 1 with corresponding values of column 2. & also sort columnn 2 with corresponding values of column 1

Comment: Note that `awk '{commands}' file` is more than enough, you don't need the `< file`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following `awk` on your result

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (x in a) print x, a[x]}' file
```

Output:

```
XXclnXXcXXcde010-bak.XX 26400
XXcwcnpde207-bak.XX 1344
XXcwcnpde148-bak.XX 1623072
XXclcnpde148-bak.XX 11808
XXcwcnpde209-bak.XX 2016
```

---

In-fact you can do the same task in single awk as follows

```
bpimagelist ... | awk '/^IMAGE/ {a[$2]+=$19} END {for (x in a) print x, a[x]}'
```

---

**EDIT** *(as per OP's comment)*

> how to get the sorted output. sort columnn 1 with corresponding values
>   of column 2. & also sort columnn 2 with corresponding values of column
>   1

Simplest approach would be to use `sort`

- Sorting on column 1

  `awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (x in a) print x, a[x]}' file | sort -k1`

  `-k1` is optional since it's default behaviour
- Sorting on column 2

  `awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (x in a) print x, a[x]}' file | sort -n -k2`

  `-n` is for numerical sort since 2nd field consists of numbers

Comment: thanks, below command worked well

awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (x in a) print x, a[x]}' file

Please let me know how to get the sorted output.

sort columnn 1 with corresponding values of column 2.
& also sort columnn 2 with corresponding values of column 1.

Comment: @user3016638 Please check EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnu Awk version 4, you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to sort the result. For example:

```
gawk -f a.awk file
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
{ a[$1]+=$2 }

END {
    print "Sorted on string value of first column:"
    print "---------------------------------------"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" 
    for (i in a) {
        print i, a[i]
    }
    print ""
    print "Sorted on numerical value of second column:"
    print "-------------------------------------------"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc" 
    for (i in a) {
        print i, a[i]
    }
}
```

gives output:

```
Sorted on string value of first column:
---------------------------------------
XXclcnpde148-bak.XX 11808
XXclnXXcXXcde010-bak.XX 26400
XXcwcnpde148-bak.XX 1623072
XXcwcnpde207-bak.XX 1344
XXcwcnpde209-bak.XX 2016

Sorted on numerical value of second column:
-------------------------------------------
XXcwcnpde207-bak.XX 1344
XXcwcnpde209-bak.XX 2016
XXclcnpde148-bak.XX 11808
XXclnXXcXXcde010-bak.XX 26400
XXcwcnpde148-bak.XX 1623072
```